# How to have multiple email backends in Django?

Tags: python, django, smtp

I would like to have both SMTP backend and console backend, so that I can send an email via SMTP while also printing the generated email to console.

In my settings.py I would like to have something like this:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = ["django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend", "django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Django supports only one email backend at a time, so providing a list of backends won't work.

But you can create your own EmailBackend like this:

```py
from django.core.mail.backends.base import BaseEmailBackend
from django.core.mail.backends.console import EmailBackend as ConsoleBackend
from django.core.mail.backends.smtp import EmailBackend as SMTPBackend


class CustomEmailBackend(BaseEmailBackend):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.smtp_backend = SMTPBackend(*args, **kwargs)
        self.console_backend = ConsoleBackend(*args, **kwargs)

    def send_messages(self, email_messages):
        smtp_count = self.smtp_backend.send_messages(email_messages)
        console_count = self.console_backend.send_messages(email_messages)

        # Maybe some validation
        # assert smtp_count == console_count, 'SMTP and Console sent different amount of emails'

        return smtp_count
```